# How do I use MVVM from within Windows Forms to display a WPF control

Tags: wpf, winforms, mvvm

I have a requirement to integrate a WPF control into an existing Windows Forms app. The simple and easiest way to do this would be to create an `ElementHost` control and set its `Child` property to my WPF View. This works fine, the view displays.

However, interacting with the view then is a bit cumbersome, and requires modifying the fields and things in the views code behind. What would be better is if I could instantiate the underlying view's view-model and interact with it in the MVVM way, having the view display and update whenever I change the properties of its view-model.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not do that with the designer, but as you add the Child of your ElementHost in code you can directly create and assign the ViewModel. As you commit changes on this ViewModel they get directly reflected in the WPF View.

```
MyView view = new MyView();
MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
view.DataContext = model;
ElementHost.Child = view;


model.SomeBoundProperty = somethingElse;
//Magic update of the WPF view
```

Comment: Thanks. this works well. I have asked another question regarding getting styles to work [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259376/getting-generic-xaml-working-from-wpf-control-embedded-in-winforms)

Answer (score -5):

The essence of MVVM is binding. Since you do not have that in Windows Forms, I am afraid you cannot use MVVM in there.

Comment: of course you can profit from the MVVM binding. Whatever change you commit on the ViewModel (also from the WinForm app) gets directly reflected in the View. And as i understood thats whats needed in this case.

Comment: He is using it inside Windows forms. As he mentioned, he has to manually change the properties, since he does not have binding there.

Comment: I do not mind being downvoted but tell something that will save someone's time and effort.