# Getting Generic.xaml working from WPF control embedded in WinForms

Tags: wpf, winforms, styles

I have a WPF control embedded in a Windows Form, which works ok. But I have all my styles for the WPF project inside Themes/Generic.xaml. When I embed the WPF control inside a Windows Forms `ElementHost` control, these styles are not picked up.

Do I need to change the WPF view to explicitly include the styles in its Resources section, or should the generic.xaml file be picked up automatically still?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is Themes/Generic.xaml in a different assembly?

The problem is that the application is not finding the ResourceDictionary where the styles are defined.

What you can do is to create a static SharedDictionaryManager class like this one:

```
public static class SharedDictionaryManager
{
    private static ResourceDictionary _sharedDictionary;
    internal static ResourceDictionary SharedDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sharedDictionary == null)
            {
                System.Uri resourceLocater =
                    new System.Uri("/assembly;component/Themes/Generic.xaml",
                                    System.UriKind.Relative);

                _sharedDictionary =
                    (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
            }

            return _sharedDictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

And when you create the HostControl you add the resource dictionary do the control:

```
ctrl.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(SharedDictionaryManager.SharedDictionary);
```

If you have more than one resource dictionary you can have one property like this for each one or you can have a property that loads all the resource dictionaries and then merge all dictionaries.

Now, the style you need should be automatically picked.